# in GWTP, when creating a new presenter, we set a NameTokens for it with a Hash Bang(!) but the code did not show Hash Bang, so where the hash bang?

Tags: gwtp

Ok, in GWTP (GWT Platform, not Gwt), when creating a new presenter in eclipse, there will be a field "Token name:" for us to set a name token. So, I added a Hash Bang at the Front of the NameToken

```
abc.client.place.NameTokens#!myname
```

& the eclipse created the java file that has

```
@NameToken(NameTokens.myname)
```

So where is the Hash Bang located (!)?

Also, suppose that when we first time create a new Presenter & we forgot to put Hash Bang in the front of the NameToken, then how can we include the Hash Bang without recreating the new Presenter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, your name tokens should be found as constant Strings in a `com.yourproject.client.place.NameTokens` class:

```
package com.yourproject.client.place;

public class NameTokens {
    public static final String home = "home";
    public static final String myname = "myname";
}
```

If you want to add the exclamation mark between the hash symbol and a name token, simply add it to the String:

```
package com.yourproject.client.place;

public class NameTokens {
    public static final String home = "home";
    public static final String myname = "!myname";
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found it, Thank you very much Simon-Pierre.